# How to specify from "this" college in "this" university?

Tags: subcontinental-english

I am confused how to write 
"B.E. with 80% from this college at this university"
in formal language

Comment: What is a "B.E."? Is this an Indian qualification?

Comment: Your question does not supply enough information for us to answer!

Comment: B.E. stands for Bachelor of Engineering @JamesWebster

Comment: Ah, I've always seen it as BEng.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

> I received a 2:1, BSc. (hons) in brains from Merton College, Oxford.

The basic formula being:

> I received a [grade], [degree type] in [subject] from [college], [university].

Of course, not all universities have colleges, so sometimes you can miss that out:

> I received a 2:2, BSc. (hons) in psychology from Plymouth University

Comment: Did you mean 2.1?

Comment: @Amory I meant [2:1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_undergraduate_degree_classification)

Comment: And here I was thinking you didn't do so well in brains!

Comment: Except you can't. Oxford doesn't offer a BSc degree.

Comment: @BarrieEngland that's true, but also noöne offers degrees in brains, either.

Comment: Coo. Thomist diacritics.